# port forwarding doesn't work at azure windows10 vm

Tags: azure, networking, port

I tried to open ports 80, 8080 for my vm, but it doesn't work.

I already added NSG inbound port rules about the ports and firewall too.

As I tested at http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/, ports like 3389, 21 is opened, But 80, 8080 is not. ( I don't know why only 3389, 21 opened )

I tried also turn the firewall off, but it is still same.

( I obviously distinguished local port / remote port in firewall )

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiF7Y.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTzK3.png)

Comment: Also make sure you're listening on `0.0.0.0:8080` not `127.0.0.1:8080` or `[::1]:8080`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think nothing wrong with your configuration but you are testing the port from the wrong site, I would suggest you test the configuration using Azure Network Watcher.
I tried the same and it has given me expected results.
please refer below screenshot.

[image]